# how use restify to connect postgreSQL to reactjs frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, restify

**Login.js**
This is **login page designed in Reactjs** and requirement is goto next page after next page after successful authentication, But **database is created using postgreSQL** and **table name is 'user'** which stores username and password. And development **requirements** are:

- **frontend** :reactjs
- **backend** : restify(nodejs)
- **Database** : postgreSQL
  So I want to know **how i can connect postgreSQL table to this login page and how authenticate user**?

```
    class Login extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                <div >
                <div >
                    <h1 >Login</h1>
                <div >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
              
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are a beginner with the concepts,

You must try to check some tutorials and then start.

Coming back to your question
I will try to answer as simple I can,

1. Frontend (react in your example) will need to consume some API (login API of your backend).
2. Your backend will be created in nodejs using restify (As per your example), this piece of code will integrate with a database which is postgress (as per your example).
3. this backend will receive the request body from say Frontend and validate in the database and give respectively user found or not found response.
4. If the user found a response your frontend will route to the next page or in case not found frontend will show error message respectively.

Hope you got the idea,

Caveat:- there will so many concepts like hashing, token, cookie, local storage, etc that will come in the journey.

Comment: ok You explain me flow of my problem and its solution, I request you to suggest me some resources to learn

Comment: on youtube just search *login with MERN stack* you will get many free tutorials

Comment: I am sorry, I was not very clear with the comment, in MERN you will get MongoDB and Express JS, but what I meant was you will understand basics and then can change express with restify and MongoDB with Postgress

Comment: 1. can u tell me, whats the difference between nodejs and restify?
2. how we can create table in postgresql in restify?

Comment: Nodejs is runtime for javascript, restify is library or framework to create APIs, I suggest learn nodejs, than express, than restify.